# Autopostback is resetting language to default on Asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like the user to select their choice of language from a drop down list. This works fine, I am using global_resource. However when I select an option from an other dropdown  (which has Autopostback =true) the language changes back to English (from french). Do I need to store the language selection in a session to prevent this and if so could I please have an example or be pointed to a tutorial. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (ddlLanguages.Items.FindByValue(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name) != null)
            {
                ddlLanguages.Items.FindByValue(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).Selected = true;
            }
        }
       
    }
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        string language = "en-GB";
        //Detect User's Language.
        if (Request.UserLanguages != null)
        {
            //Set the Language.
            language = Request.UserLanguages[0];
        }
        //Check if PostBack is caused by Language DropDownList.
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains("ddlLanguages"))
        {
            //Set the Language.
            language = Request.Form[Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]];
        }
        //Set the Culture.
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
    }
    protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblShow.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have an `if(!Page.IsPostback)` in your `Page_Load`? post some code

Comment: Yes I have, but this makes no difference! I will post code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to store your user choice of language in a session and use the value in future page requests

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        string language = "en-GB";
        //Detect User's Language.
       // if (Request.UserLanguages != null)
       // {
            //Set the Language.
      //      language = Request.UserLanguages[0];
      //  }
        //Check if PostBack is caused by Language DropDownList.
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] != null && Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains("ddlLanguages"))
        {
            //Set the Language.
            language = Request.Form[Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]];
            Session["language"]=language.ToString();
        }
      else
       {
            if(Session["language"] !=null){
            language=Session["language"].ToString();
             }
       }
        //Set the Culture.
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the language in session or a cookie. What's happening now is that when you init a postback from some other control then the language is set at the row 
`language = Request.UserLanguages[0];`

which I assume is English. Session/cookie solution would also enable you to persist language choice for other non-postback requests from the same user.

Comment: Thank you Martin, you answered also but shreesha's example did the job. Your explanation was useful. Thank you for your advice.